# Error 0x8007000 on installing WSL

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm learning C and would like to use VS Code with WSL as my programming environment.

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad L460 running Windows 10.

I was able to install VS Code, but got the following error 0x8007000e when I tried installing WSL in PowerShell using `wsl --install`:

```
A error was encountered during installation, but installation may continue. Component: 'Ubuntu' Error Code: 0x8007000e
The requested operation is successful. Changes will not be effective until the system is rebooted.
```

I'm not sure what this error means. [This thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2407) says it's due to insufficient storage. I have enough (110GB) free disk space available, so I thought maybe it's complaining about my RAM (4GB)? **I'd be grateful if someone could shed some light on this, as I'm a total noob and don't want to break anything.**

I've looked into Visual Studio, but I'll be writing many small programs and don't want to create a new project for each. The other option I've come across is VirtualBox, but I've never used VM before and don't want to break anything.

---

**EDIT:** Running `wsl -l -v` in command prompt returns:

[image]

---

EDIT: After following the manual install steps given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual), I get `WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102`:

[image: WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102]

My system information for Hyper-V Requirements shows:

```
VM Monitor Mode Extensions: Yes
Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware: No
Second Level Address Translation Extensions: Yes
Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection: Yes
```

---

**UPDATE:** Switching to WSL 1 almost worked. I was able to install Ubuntu  22.04 LTS, but got a weirdly named command prompt called "root@DESKTOP-SAM07NG" upon completion and was not asked to create a login (as shown in [Step 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-6---install-your-linux-distribution-of-choice)).

I then installed the Remote Development extension pack for VS Code as required [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_getting-started).

However, I was unable to open a remote folder from the WSL terminal according to [Step 3](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_open-a-remote-folder-or-workspace):

[image]

The suggested workaround can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1856#issuecomment-554436732).

Some users had success with upgrading their gzip. I'm not sure how to check my version, (running `root@DESKTOP-5AM07NG:~# gzip --version` just returns `-bash: /usr/bin/gzip: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.), but I did see `gzip` in the list returned by `apt list --upgradable`. So I tried updating it with `~# sudo apt install gzip`.

Retrying [Step 3](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_open-a-remote-folder-or-workspace), I get:

[image]

...and VS Code launches, but no folder is opened:

[image]

Comment: "space requirements" is talking about your physical storage not the amount of system memory your device has. You should [edit] your question to indicate the version of Windows 10.  [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264102/wsl-2-wont-run-ubuntu-error-0x80370102) might be helpful

Comment: You should be installing Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store, not PowerShell, if Windows 10 is up to date. Check also your disk free space.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, I have 110GB of disk space remaining.

Comment: @Thanks harrymc, I used PowerShell per the instructions on [Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install).

Comment: @user173972 So just for clarity, a `wsl --install`?  At this point, does `wsl -l -v` show anything?  (Again, remember to edit into the question since the results may be difficult to read in a comment) -- Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @NotTheDr01ds, I've added the screenshot to my post as an edit. So it hasn't yet been installed?

Comment: @user173972 That's correct.  Try working through the steps in [Manual installation steps for WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual) and see if we can figure out exactly where it's failing.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, I got to step 6 and chose Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, but install failed with `error: 0x80370102 Please enable the Virtual Machine Platform Windows feature and ensure virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.` (I've added a screenshot) :(

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, not sure if this is relevant but my system info summary says `Hyper-V - VM Monitor Mode Extensions Yes`, `Hyper-V - Second Level Address Translation Extensions Yes`, `Hyper-V - Data Execution Protection Yes`, but `Hyper-V - Virtualization Enabled in Firmware   No`.

Comment: Downgrading to WSL1 worked for [this user](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4120#issuecomment-937938527) and others that posted after them. Should I try doing the same?

Comment: Sorry, the link in my previous comment is incorrect. I meant to link to [this post](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4120#issuecomment-1136741629).

Comment: @user173972 You can use WSL1 if you can't get around it any other way, but I think you are just a simple step away (hopefully) from having this working.  The info you indicates that your CPU supports the virtualization needed, but it just isn't turned on in the BIOS.  Try [these steps](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-l-series-laptops/thinkpad-l460/solutions/ht500006-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-lenovo-computers) and see if you get further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the Core i5-6300U in your ThinkPad L460 should support the virtualization needed for WSL2, but it hasn't been enabled in the BIOS.  Your System Information results back that up.

Try [these steps](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-l-series-laptops/thinkpad-l460/solutions/ht500006-how-to-enable-virtualization-technology-on-lenovo-computers) from Lenovo for enabling virtualization, summarized here:

- Enter the BIOS by rebooting the computer and holding <kbd>F1</kbd> at power-on.
- Find the *Security* tab in the BIOS
- Enable the *Intel Virtualization Technology* (may be called *VT-x*)
- Save the changed with <kbd>F10</kbd> and reboot
- Check `systeminfo.exe` again and see if your results have changed

Then try enabling the *Virtual Machine Platform* option again.

After that try installing Ubuntu.  At this point, you can probably do this most easily by running `ubuntu.exe install --ui=none`.  This will skip the graphical install and just ask for a username and password.

If you continue to experience problems, leave me a comment, but also continue to update your question with the latest info.

Comment: thank you so much for walking me through this, I really appreciate your help and patience. I ended up switching to WSL 1 last night before seeing your answer this morning (I'm in NZ), but encountered a problem with `gzip`. I've added an update to my post, but would totally understand if you don't have the time to look into it as it's a different problem from the one in my original post.

Comment: @user173972 The `gzip` issue should be resolved by a `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`.  See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417322/1165986) for details, and let me know if that's still not working for some reason.  The `root` issue is one that you really should take care of, though.  What's your `wsl -l -v` show now -- `Ubuntu` or `Ubuntu-22.04`?

Comment: Thanks for getting back, it's showing `NAME: Ubuntu-22.04    STATE: Running    VERSION: 2`. I followed your instructions to enable VTT and VT-d in BIOS, ran `wsl --set-default-version 2` in PowerShell and uninstalled Ubuntu and reinstalled it through the MS store. This time I got the orange graphical install and I could even sign up :) I still can't open folders in VS Code from the WSL command line.

Comment: @user173972 It's not still giving you `gzip` issues when attempting to open a folder in VScode, though, is it?

Comment: No, thankfully. And the folder wasn't opening up because dingus me was typing `code` instead of `code .`. It all works as it should now. Thank you for all your help :)